# how to ignore id after contrller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I used Pagination in CodeIgniter.

This is my link in address bar on my localhost

`PicTraveller/branches/1.0.1/Implementation/index.php/home`

When I click on next then next 5 records will show. After I click on next:
`PicTraveller/branches/1.0.1/Implementation/index.php/home/5`

I then have to write for this in routes file:
`$route['home/(:any)']= 'home/$1';`

But this is not work . Please suggest me. Thanks in advance

Comment: home is my controller

Answer (score 0):

You can write this without using routes as follow:
Pass parameter to function index on your home conroller in that your code is placed.
Parameter should be nullable as fist no record number is send.
i.e.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index($recordId = null) {
        if (!empty($recordId)) {
            //next button is clicked
        } else {
            // first time 
        }
    }
}
```